# Ajax in Rails, it doesn't work because it jumps to other page without staying in current page.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am in entry level of Rails. I has made the database (whose name is "shop") with scaffold. Also I made the page which shows the overview of table and jumps to other page which shows the specific information of record.
Now I try to make the page that the specific information of record is shown in the same page of the overview of table when the "show" link on the one row of table is clicked.

However, despite of my expectation, it jumps to other page as I already have done.
I used many hours about this so would like to have someone's help.

Thank you.

\app\controllers\shops_controller.rb

```
        class ShopsController < ApplicationController

        # GET /shops
        # GET /shops.json
        def index
            @shops = Shop.all

            respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @shops }
        end
    end

    # GET /shops/1
    # GET /shops/1.json
    def show
        @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { render layout: (request.headers["X-Requested-With"] != 'XMLHttpRequest') }
          format.json { render json: @shop }
        end
    end

    # GET /shops/new
    # GET /shops/new.json
    def new
        @shop = Shop.new

        respond_to do |format|
         format.html # new.html.erb
         format.json { render json: @shop }
        end
    end

    # GET /shops/1/edit
    def edit
        @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
    end

    # POST /shops
    # POST /shops.json
    def create
        @shop = Shop.new(params[:shop])

        respond_to do |format|
         if @shop.save
            format.html { redirect_to @shop, notice: 'Shop was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @shop, status: :created, location: @shop }
         else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
         end
        end
    end

    # PUT /shops/1
    # PUT /shops/1.json
    def update
        @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @shop.update_attributes(params[:shop])
            format.html { redirect_to @shop, notice: 'Shop was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
          else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
            format.json { render json: @shop.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
    end

    # DELETE /shops/1
    # DELETE /shops/1.json
    def destroy
        @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])
        @shop.destroy

        respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to shops_url }
         format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end
end
```

\app\views\shops\index.html.erb

```
    <h2>Shops</h2>

    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Link_ID</th>
        <th>Offer</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    <% @shops.each do |shop| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= shop.name %></td>
        <td><%= shop.link_id %></td>
        <td><%= shop.offer %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', shop, :remote => true, "data-type" => "html", :class => 'show' %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_shop_path(shop) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', shop, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>

    <br />

    <div id="show_area"></div>
        <%= javascript_tag do %>
            $('a.show').on('ajax:success', function (data, status, xhr) {
            $('#show_area').html(status);})
        <% end %>
```

\app\views\shops\show.js.erb

```
    $('#show_area').html("<%= raw(j(render :partial => 'show_body')) %>")
```

Comment: If you make it 'data: {type: "script"}' instead of yours "data-type" etc does it change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have jquery rails in your gemfile (gem 'jquery-rails') and have:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

in your application.js, what you've got there *should* work.  Minus the show.js.erb, which would require you changing the data-type to be script instead of html.  Although based on your description, the show.js.erb wouldn't be needed.  The script you have in index.html.erb will suffice.